# Print turns into spaghetti on Ender 3 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality

So I was printing a low poly bunny and all of a sudden the new layers didn't adhere to the other layers. I don't think it was printing an overhang.

I have an ender 3 pro which I use together with Cura. I print in PLA at 200 °C. The print bed is set to  60 °C. I use a print cooling fan at 100 %. The layer height I set to 0.2 mm, the line width 0.4 mm from the 0.4 mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 30 mm/s for outer walls, 60 mm/s for inner walls, and 60 mm/s for infill. My retraction is 6.5 mm

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with 'spaghetti' errors]

Comment: I had similar problems after replacing the nozzle. It would start printing ok but then after a certain point it would block up and then unblock itself after a layer or two and start printing in air. Have you tried swapping out your nozzle for a fresh one?

Comment: Did the print stay adhered to the bed during the spaghettification? Do you have an idea on what it was printing when it turned to spaghetti?

Comment: Thanks for filling out the template, but I'm afraid this isn't enough to answer the question. This could be caused by layer shift, print adhesion failing, we need more info how this happened.

Answer (score 2):

If the print didn't stay adhered to the bed during the spaghettification, depending on where it was in the print (outer wall, inner wall, infill), I suspect that you might be printing too fast for that area.

This would cause friction to build enough to shift the print or even knock it over, and then you're printing in the air with nothing to support it.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please don't put additional follow-up questions in your answer... that is what the comments section under the question is for. Please take the [tour] to get a better understanding of how the Q&A mechanism of Stack Exchange works. Please put the follow up questions as comments under the question (and [edit] and remove them from your answer), leaving just your proposed solution in your answer. Thanks. (Note: I have done this for you as you don't currently have enough reputation points (50).